# Download address from firebase in mapView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit, mkmapview

Trying to upload an address from firebase and post it on mapView. But for some reason the address doesn't want to unload. The address spelled out by the string in firebase example - **Moscow, Street so-and-so, house 1**. What could be the reason for not loading the data?

```
var allAddresses: String = ""

addressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Address")

addressRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        self.allAddresses = value["address"] as? String ?? ""
    })
}
```

Firebase:

```
{
  «Address» : {
    «AddressOne» : {
      "address" : "Москва, Пресненская набережная д.8, квартира 195, подъезд 94",
    },
    "AddressTwo» : {
      "address" : "Москва, ул. Правды д.24 строение 3",
    },
    "AddressThree» : {
      "address" : "Москва,ул.Электрозаводская д.21",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where in the JSON does `addressRef` point to?

Comment: addressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Address")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a value observer to `/Address`, which means that you get a snapshot with all data at that location. Since there are multiple child addresses, your code will need to handle those.

The simplest way to do that is by listening for `.childAdded` instead of `.value`:

```
var allAddresses: String = ""

addressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Address")

addressRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

    self.allAddresses = value["address"] as? String ?? ""
})
```

Now your code gets triggered with each individual address.

You can also stick to observing `.value` and then loop over the results in the snapshot:

```
var allAddresses: String = ""

addressRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Address")

addressRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for address in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        let value = address.value as! NSDictionary

        self.allAddresses = value["address"] as? String ?? ""
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional unwrapping and set breakpoints on some lines to see where your code doesn't do what you want :

```
var allAddresses: String = ""

addressRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            if let address = value["address"] as? String {
                self.allAddresses =  address
            } else {
                print("no address in value")
            }
        } else {
            print("no value from firebase")
        }
    })
}
```

You should also use swift types in swift, it's a good practice.

Comment: Hmm, it helped me a bit, i got a print "no address in value".
And i added JSON file from firebase in question.

Comment: set a breakpoint inside the completion block and look what is the value of snapshot

Comment: allAddresses String ""  
   

Maybe I'm not correctly extract the data from the firebase...

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at line "if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {" and print snapshot but it doesn't show your datas, you should check if your addressRef is right.

Comment: i got a print:

[«AddressOne»: {
    address = "\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U0430, \U041f\U0440\U0435\U0441\U043d\U0435\U043d\U0441\U043a\U0430\U044f \U043d\U0430\U0431\U0435\U0440\U0435\U0436\U043d\U0430\U044f \U0434.8, \U043a\U0432\U0430\U0440\U0442\U0438\U0440\...\U0434 94";
}, 
"AddressTwo»: {
    address = "\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U0430,\U0443\U043b.\U042d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U0437\U0430\...\U0434.21";
},
«AddressThree»: {
    address = "\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U0430, \U0443\U043b. \U041f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0434\U044b \U0434.24 \...\U0435 3";
}]

Comment: This is not properly JSON formatted. I don't know what went wrong but the problem is probably in here.